# Expanding an array object and moving a pointer?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

```
Term *temp;
temp = new Term[(getCapacity() + 1)];
capacity++;
temp = ptr;
ptr[getEltsInUse()] = T;
eltsInUse++;
delete [] ptr; // reclaim space
ptr = temp;
```

I'm working with an Array object and here I am trying to add an object to the array when it is full. Here it declares the temp pointer one size bigger and copies the original over to temp, then deletes the original. The last line is meant to be moving the ptr pointer to point at the same thing as temp but I'm not sure I did that right. The pseudo-code I was given is:

1. Declare Term *temp
2. new an array of Term of size capacity+1 for temp to point at
3. inc capacity
4. Copy the elements of the ptr array to temp array
5. Put the new Term on the end
6. inc eltsInUse
7. delete ptr to free up the old array
8. Set ptr tpoint where temp points (the newly built array)

Sorry if this a really obvious answer.

Comment: `temp = ptr;` You have now lost the memory you just allocated, why is that even in there?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
Term *temp;
temp = new Term[capacity + 1];     //allocate memory for capacity + 1

for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) //copy the old data to the new memory
    temp[i] = ptr[i];

temp[capacity++] = NewElement;     //copy new element to last place in new memory
delete ptr;                        //free old memory.
ptr = temp;
```